# codeigniter class name convention

Tags: codeigniter-2

When I'm developing in NetBeans I have a lot of confusion due to the amount of tabs open. In most cases the controller has the same name of the view or model.
In the [convention style guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/styleguide.html) they say that you can prefix a controller file name with a custom suffix, but doesn't work.
My question is, there is any chance to end all the controller files with "_controller"?
In my example the class is `class Verify_login extends CI_Controller {` and the file is named `verify_login.php`. Tried with `controller.verify_login.php` like they say in the guideline but as I say, doesn't work. Lots of confusion in codeigniter's documentation.

Comment: If you have any interest in moving to CI 3 you may want to check out the new conventions.  I know model classes all have to start with a uppercase letter now.  Cannot remember if it is the same for controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Since the controller is the only thing exposed in the URL, I usually name my views and models with an indicator like "user_view" or "user_model". The controller would just be "user" and in this way I always know which file I'm working on.